# How to link commits to User Story automatically using Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, commit, user-stories, git-repo

I have a git repo in Azure DevOps Repos, I also have a test User Story set up. I want to set up user story to be linked to my commits automatically. Please help how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you need to add certain syntax to your commit messages. You need to add # followed by the work item number into the commit message. You can also add keywords like Fix or InProgress to update the user story via the commit message.

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/add-links-to-work-items?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) should get you started

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using visual studio to commit codes. Could you please tell me how can I set up in visual studio. So that my commits automatically links to User Story.

Comment: It will be as simple as making sure that you always commit your code with the correct syntax (#ID) to link to the relevant user story, along with an option keyword to update the progress and optional commit text to explain the code changes